# Solving for auto-regression coefficients when covariance is singular?

Tags: regression, covariance

I need coefficients of autoregressive model of $x$: matrix $B$ with zero diagonal which minimizes squared error:

$$\text{argmin}_B E[||x - Bx||^2]$$

For non-singular covariance, I can get solution [directly](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tXmS6kZcJ8hsfvzKaZSCvXf7iNRT25UG#scrollTo=mTMmob1gJ9Zc) from $E[xx']^{-1}$ using following procedure:

1. Let $D2$ be the inverse second moment with off-diagonal terms set to zero
   $$D2=E[xx']^{-1}_d$$
2. Read coefficients $\{a_1\ldots a_n\}$ for the model $x_i=a_0 x_0 + \ldots a_n x_n$ from $i$th row of following matrix

$$B=I-(X'X)^{-1} D2^{-1}$$

**What should I do for singular $E[xx']$?**

For instance, suppose

$$X=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & -1 & -2 & 1 \\
 -2 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

I can turn this into 4 regression problems, solve each problem using $\beta=(X'X)^{-1}(Y'X)$, and get following coefficients of auto-regressive model with $x=Bx$
$$B=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{7}{4} & \frac{7}{8} \\
 -2 & 0 & \frac{7}{2} & \frac{7}{4} \\
 \frac{4}{7} & \frac{2}{7} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{8}{7} & \frac{4}{7} & -2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

1. This [requires](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tXmS6kZcJ8hsfvzKaZSCvXf7iNRT25UG#scrollTo=v8XckVuKJqk9) 4 matrix inversions, whereas for non-singular covariance matrix I had to only do 1
2. This is a well-posed problem, but in general it may be ill-posed, so one would use some linear solver instead of $(X'X)^{-1}(Y'X)$ formula. However, calling linear solver for each column is too expensive.

**Edit**

Aksakal suggested to use regularized estimator for inverting the covariance, trying this out [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1tXmS6kZcJ8hsfvzKaZSCvXf7iNRT25UG#scrollTo=wAqcbZQaqfOW)

Using shrunk covariance estimator with very small lambda gives good results. Numerically inverting singular covariance without regularization and sticking it into the formula gives slightly better error.

```
Error direct:  1.4051584874249273e-30
Error inverse:  3.2047474274603605e-30
Error Ledoit-Wolf:  9.351834226497054
Error shrunk covariance:  0.7203818230423954
Error very-shrunk covariance:  0.00952058588215488
```

Comment: Your comparisons are problematic. The better way to compare would be to start with a known lag structure, then generate the set of rank deficient samples from it. Then study properties of different estimates of lag coefficients. Currently you are looking at a single sample so any conclusions you make are going to be highly uncertain

Comment: I think it's an issue of Ledoit-Wolf optimizing for different objective. To get coefficients, I divide entries of precision matrix by entries of the diagonal of the precision matrix. Small bias in the precision matrix estimation produces large error in the coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is rank rank-deficient, not necessarily singular when you have more variables than observations.

You could regularize the covariance matrix before operating it, e.g. using Ledoit-Wolf method:

```
Sig = np.cov(Y.T)
iSig = np.linalg.inv(Sig)

from sklearn.covariance import LedoitWolf

RSig = LedoitWolf().fit(Y)
iRSig = np.linalg.inv(RSig.covariance_)
print('ordinary:',iSig, '\nregilarized: ', iRSig)
```

Output

```
ordinary: [[ 1.40737488e+14  2.81474977e+14  7.50599938e+14 -1.40737488e+15]
 [ 2.81474977e+14  5.62949953e+14  1.50119988e+15 -2.81474977e+15]
 [-1.68884986e+15 -3.37769972e+15  3.00239975e+15 -1.12589991e+15]
 [ 2.25179981e+15  4.50359963e+15 -6.00479950e+15  4.50359963e+15]] 
regilarized:  [[ 0.45698883  0.17402552 -0.14171221 -0.0944748 ]
 [ 0.17402552  0.80670551 -0.15040682 -0.10027121]
 [-0.14171221 -0.15040682  0.6620951  -0.22126292]
 [-0.0944748  -0.10027121 -0.22126292  0.84648087]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I actually get much better results by replacing `LedoitWolf` with `ShrunkCovariance`, updated question with link to code. Both of them are worse than just numerically inverting the singular covariance matrix and sticking the result into formula -- formula divides by diagonal, so the resulting coefs become reasonable. This is a general problem with regularization, optimal lambda is problem specific, hard to check for correctness

Comment: Ledoit wolf shrinks to a certain kind of a matrix. You can use the idea to shrink to something else, if you have a better target matrix. For instance, you could use a diagonal matrix or scaled identity matrix